# Cannot insert information into database through form on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created an insert form in Codeigniter, I have linked the controller and the model and I have also linked them both to the database that the form should insert the data into.

However when I try to input information and submit, nothing is entered into my database.

Controller:

```
public function insertjob()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $data['title']="Add a new job";
    $this->load->view("insertjob", $data);
}

public function addingjob()
{
    $jobtype=$this->input->post('jobtype');
    $jobinfo=$this->input->post('jobinfo');
    $this->load->model("cmodel");
    if($this->cmodel->addjob($jobtype, $jobinfo)){
        $data['msg']="New job addition successful";
    } else {
        $data['msg']="There was an error please try again";
    }
    $this->load->view("confirmation",$data);
}
```

Model:

```
function details(){
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('clientjobs')->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function addjob($jobtype,$jobinfo)
{
    $newjob=array("jobtype"=>$jobtype,"jobinfo"=>$jobinfo);
    return $this->db->insert('clientjobs', $newjob);
}
```

Comment: In your database file is db_debug set to true? This might give you an error.  The code looks fine.

Comment: Yes it is, what do i set it to?

Comment: Leave it as true, until you have sorted the issue.  Your getting no errors at all?!?

Comment: No, no error message comes up the page just refreshes which simulates the insert but nothing enters the database.

Comment: When you submit are you getting a blank page?

Comment: When i submit the page refreshes

Comment: @user3616649 i suggest you go step by step first check up to **`insert`** remove return and add an exit here replace this code `return $this->db->insert('clientjobs', $newjob);` with this `$this->db->insert('clientjobs', $newjob); exit;` and than go to database and check if row inserted an also if you give us full code related with this along db than it can be easy to help you

Comment: you also add here view file code so easily we can understood your issue.